Make webapp hosted in private network available publicly, but restricted to verified users
I've got an app that is being hosted on a private network. It's meant for private use, does not have authentication functionality as I'm the only user. I used to connect to it using Zerotier, but now I need to access it on a corporate laptop with another VPN enabled. Enabling this VPN means, I'm losing access to Zerotier services. Corporate policies limit my ability to configure it.
What is an easiest (and possibly cheap) solution to give me access to my app through corporate VPN? That probably means making my app public and using some service offering secured reverse proxy, but other viable options are also welcome
